# Omitir espacios vacíos en cadenas de Python con la función zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, iteradores

Tengo el siguiente código en el que intento imprimir los valores de las listas en conjunto usando la función `zip`.

El caso es que me gustaría imprimir todos los valores de la primera lista y en caso de que en las otras listas no haya un valor correspondiente al valor `4`, se imprima un espacio en blanco o nada.

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lista2 = ["Rojo","Azul","Verde"]
lista3 = ["Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes"]

for z, x, y in zip(lista1,lista2,lista3):
    print (z,x,y)
```

El output de este código es el siguiente:

```
1 Rojo Lunes
2 Azul Martes
3 Verde Miercoles
```

El output que quiero obtener:

```
1 Rojo Lunes
2 Azul Martes
3 Verde Miercoles
4 Jueves
5 Viernes
```

Answer (score 2):

Python tiene en su biblioteca estandar otras funciones que complementan al lenguaje, en este caso puedes usar `zip_longest` del módulo `itertools`. Este módulo, como su propio nombre indica, está compuesto de funciones que ayudan a crear iteradores de forma eficiente. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lista2 = ["Rojo","Azul","Verde"]
lista3 = ["Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes"]

for z, x, y in zip_longest(lista1,lista2,lista3, fillvalue=""):
    print (z,x,y)
```

**Salida:**

```
1 Rojo Lunes
2 Azul Martes
3 Verde Miercoles
4  Jueves
5  Viernes
```

`zip_longest` crea un iterador que tendra la longitud máxima de las colecciones que se le hayan pasado. Con el argumento `fillvalue` se le indica con que se quiere rellenar los elementos que falten, por defecto es `None`.

Puedes saber más sobre `zip_longest` en la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener el resultado deseado de la siguiente manera:

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lista2 = ["Rojo","Azul","Verde"]
lista3 = ["Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes"]
indice = 0 #declaras la variable indice

while indice < len(lista1): # repetimos mientras no hayamos llegado al final de la lista1
    if(indice<len(lista2)): #si el indice de la lista 1 es menor que el de la lista2
         print(lista1[indice], lista2[indice], lista3[indice]) #imprimimos todas las listas
    else:
         print(lista1[indice], lista3[indice]) #si no imprimimos solo la lista1 y la lista3 
    indice += 1 #incrementamos el indice en uno
```